# Ejecutar un .exe desde PHP usando Windows Server + Apache

Tags: php, apache

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web para automatizar un proceso.

El caso es que la única forma que he encontrado para automatizar dicho proceso es utilizar Windows y hacer un script con AutoIt v3, que puedo compilar en forma de .exe.

El script lo tengo funcionando, el servidor web de Apache también. Si ejecuto el php desde el cmd de Windows el .exe se abre y se ejecuta sin problema, sin embargo, el mismo script desde el servidor web se queda cargando hasta que da un timeout.

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Edito y añado el código

```
<?php
    shell_exec('C:\xampp\htdocs\informe.exe');
?>
```

He probado tanto con exec() como con shell_exec(), creo que el problema está en que Apache no llega a ejecutarlo. He permitido en los servicios de Windows Server que el servicio de Apache interactúe con el escritorio.

EDITO: Efectivamente, debe ser un tema de permisos de Apache, si detengo el servicio de Apache y inicio httpd.exe el script funciona sin problema.

Comment: ¿Qué sentencia estás usando, `shell_exec`? (siempre hay que incluir el código en las preguntas) ¿Qué permisos tiene el usuario que corre el proceso de Apache? ¿Tiene acceso a la carpeta del exe para ejecutar?

Comment: He probado tanto con exec() como con shell_exec(), creo que el problema es precisamente de Apache. El .exe esta dentro de la carpeta htdocs y junto al .php

Comment: si te da un timeout, suena mas bien a que la tarea es larga (por ej, 5min) y necesitas configurar en el php.ini del servidor apache mas tiempo (normalmente tiene 30sec). Personalmente no veo efectivo eso. No sera mejor una tarea programada para que la ejecutes cada x minutos? Cual es la necesidad de arrancar ese script por web?

Comment: ¿No puedes crear una tarea programada que se ejecute igual que lo haces en CMD?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente era culpa de ejecutar Apache como un servicio.

Ejecutando Apache añadiendo un acceso directo al inicio funciona perfectamente. No es la solución perfecta, pero funciona.

Gracias a todos.